# Cannot install QtWebEngine

Tags: python

So I'am using a Raspberry Pi 400, and building a project in Python using  PyQtWebEngine. However, I try running the command:

```
pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

Instead of installing it like usual, I receive many errors in return:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting PyQtWebEngine
  Using cached PyQtWebEngine-5.15.5.tar.gz (48 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpz_vohqu5_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp_3pe9lrj
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ys67he0l/pyqtwebengine_db2bf7854d4643119a569e6142798c96
    Complete output (29 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/tmpz_vohqu5_in_process.py", line 126, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
    
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpz_vohqu5_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/tmpz_vohqu5_in_process.py", line 263, in main
    json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
  File "/tmp/tmpz_vohqu5_in_process.py", line 130, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    return _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel(backend, metadata_directory,
  File "/tmp/tmpz_vohqu5_in_process.py", line 159, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
    whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5qmj2una/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
    project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5qmj2una/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
    project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5qmj2una/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 587, in setup
    self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5qmj2una/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
    super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5qmj2una/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 234, in apply_user_defaults
    self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5qmj2una/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
    raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/66/56e118abb4cddd8e4bea6f89bdec834069b52479fb991748f1b21950811e/PyQtWebEngine-5.15.5.tar.gz#sha256=ab47608dccf2b5e4b950d5a3cc704b17711af035024d07a9b71ad29fc103b941 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqtwebengine/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpz_vohqu5_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp_3pe9lrj Check the logs for full command output.
```

Help?

Note: An easier way to say this is that, the command errors out with exit status 1 for some reason.

Comment: Can you please add some more details regarding the virtual environment (if any) used, the python and pip version.

Comment: Listen, I'am using Python 3.8.5 and it doesn't matter if I use pip3